# Vue JS 2. How to prevent reload same nested component when navigate between two parent?

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vuejs2, vue-router

I have Menu component, that is nested in two different layouts. When I navigate between these two parent component, Vue reloads nested component every time. It cause a problem: Menu's scroll position goes to 0:0 when page is reload. I tried to use , but it didn't work.

How can I prevent same nested component reloading when switching between two parents?

Answer (score 0):

It seems you are using the same store/data options in two different layouts.
Try to save your data in the parents components and only pass it to your menu via props.